# Why do CSS filters not affect the background image of the html element?

Tags: css-filters

This blurs everything, except the background of `<html>`.

```
html {
    background:linear-gradient(black 50%, white 50%);
    filter:blur(20px);
}
```

Comment: Is this a Chrome bug? (I will test it in other browsers later.)

Comment: Is this an imperfection of the CSS specification?

Comment: Is this intentional and reasonable?

Comment: I know I could modify the percentages of the `linear-gradient` to achieve the desired visual effect, but I'm interested in **the reason of the unexpected and seemingly irrational behaviour** of the filter.